# Update wordpress database with external database in firebird

Tags: php, wordpress, firebird

I have a physical store and would like to integrate the system that already exists and works as a wordpress stock. However the software database is local, using firebird. Is this possible? Is there any plugin for wordpress? Where do I start?

In short, I would like to take the stock data r information that is missing from the wordpress database and add.

A friend said he needs to create a procedure, is that correct?

I'm using wordpress 5.4.1.

Comment: Your question is too vague and broad.

Comment: you have to start with learning programming in PHP